# How does this oxazolone behave as an acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

how can you explain the increased acidity (pka around 14) of this oxazolone compared to a standard cyclic amide/lactam)?

[image]

Comment: It's a cyclic carbamate so not really comparable to a lactam. The O has a major electron'withdrawing effect. The enolate/anion is also stabilised by delocalisation.

Comment: so would the most acidic proton be @ N? Is both inductive and mesomeric delocalisation at work in the conjugate base?

Comment: Yes, the NH is most acidic and both factors contribute to make the conjugate base stable.

Comment: Better question may be why it would be only that weakly acidic.

Answer (score 2):

It's a cyclic carbamate so not really comparable to a lactam. The O has a major electron withdrawing effect. The enolate/anion is also stabilised by delocalisation.

[image]